# How many times in a day would System.DateTime.Now.Ticks % 1000 > 1000 return true?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

**Updated**

How many times a day would `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks % 1000 > 1000` return true?

I am writing a program that gathers occurrences of an event in a static Dictionary. I want to commit the dictionary to persistent storage on a regular basis, but too often since the rate of change of the Value in each member is frequent.

Co-worker suggested using System.DateTime.Now.Ticks as a random number and doing a Mod on that number.
I am just not sure how to determine how often this will return true.

**My Class:**

I am wanting to commit the Dictionary to SQL 100-ish times per day. The dictionary will be updated about 250,000,000 times/day with about 1000 keys.

```
public static class StackTraceLogger
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> Data = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

        public static void Log(StackTrace st)
        {
            if (Data.ContainsKey(st.ToString()))
            {
                var val = 0;
                if (Data.TryGetValue(st.ToString(), out val))
                {
                    var newVal = val + 1;
                    Data.TryUpdate(st.ToString(), newVal, val);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Data.TryAdd(st.ToString(), 1);
            }

            // Periodically log the dictionary to SQL
            if (System.DateTime.Now.Ticks % 1000 > 1000)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> m in Data)
                {
                    Debugger.Log(m.Value.ToString(), m.Key);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: In what language are you programming that the mod operator can return undefined results? Assuming the language is not wacky, zero.

Comment: How about basing the commit to permanent storage on the number of changes, with a fallback to once-every-(some time interval) if it hasn't been written? Oh, and also on closing the program.

Comment: Your coworker's idea is a bad idea. Extracting randomness from timing data is a task that only a tiny handful of people know how to do correctly. If you want random numbers then use a random number generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 86,400 seconds in a day. If you want to do something 100 times per day, then you have to do it once every 864 seconds. The easiest way to do that is to start a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) that fires once every 864 seconds.

For example:

```
using System.Threading;
public class MyClass
{
    // whatever stuff you have

    // Timer that will update the data
    private Timer _updateTimer;

    public MyClass()
    {
        // initialization

        // Start the timer
        _updateTimer = new Timer(
            UpdateTimerProc, null, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(864),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(864));
    }

    private void UpdateTimerProc(object state)
    {
        // do SQL update here
    }
}
```

Be aware that the `UpdateTimerProc` will be executed on a separate thread when the timer fires--once every 864 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question as asked is `0`.

`x % n < n` for all x and n.   For example,  `99999999 % 1000 == 999`, which is less than 1000.

But if you want a random number - why not just use the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random.aspx) class?

I'm not following the bit about the dictionary and how a random number would help you.

Comment: As `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks` is an Int64, it is perhaps worth noting that if it is negative `x % n < n` is still true.

Comment: I have updated with more details. I see your point about my current expression, but what can I use to get the desired cadence of 100-ish times per days having the if condition evaluate `True`

Comment: This is the wrong approach entirely.  You can't count on your code running at the exact moment of any alignment to the current time.  You should instead have a `Timer` that fires at a particular interval.  Every 15 minutes is 96 times daily (on most days).

Answer (score 0):

This code will check if it passes 864 seconds since last update. 864 seconds appear 100 times during 24 hours.

Try

```
 var currentTimeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.Second;

        if ((currentTimeStamp - lastTimeStamp) > 864)
        {
            // store
            lastTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp;
        }
```